# FadeToggle fade duration

Tags: javascript, jquery, fade

this is possibly a stupid question but I cannot figure it out how can I increase the fade duration?

```
window.switchIn = function () {
$('.red').fadeToggle(function(){
    $('.blue').fadeToggle(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {window.switchOut();}, 3000);
    });
});

}

setTimeout(function() {window.switchIn();}, 3000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('yourSelector').fadeToggle(yourDuration,function() { functionstoExecute});
```

[From jQuery Doc](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/)

```
.fadeToggle( [duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )
```

**duration** (default: 400)

Type: ***Number or String***

A string or number determining how long the animation will run.

Comment: are you sure the `yourDuration` goes after? http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/

Answer (score 0):

example in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DhDUV/

```
<input onclick="$('#x').fadeToggle(1000);" type="button" value="toggle" />
<div id="x">fade text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set duration in [`.fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/).

> duration (default: 400)
>
> Type: Number or String A string or number
>
> determining how long the animation will run.

Try this :

```
 $('.blue').fadeToggle("slow", function() {
        //-- Your code
    });
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ypHnH/)